# Confusion around case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on updating some older code for our system and I am not understanding why a check for an edit control is working in a static case.

Here is the code:

```
switch(nCtlColor)
{
case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:
    {
        if( ((pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_EDIT_SP_FROM) || (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_EDIT_SP_TO)) && 
            (m_RadioDateSelection == 0) )
        {
            pDC->SetBkColor(g_crSectionLTBlue);
            hbr = g_cbSectionLTBlue;
            break;
        }

        pDC->SetTextColor(g_crBlack);
        hbr = g_cbSectionLTBlue;
        pDC->SetBkColor(g_crSectionLTBlue);
    }
    break;

case CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX:
    pDC->SetTextColor(g_crBlack);
    pDC->SetBkColor(g_crWhite);
    hbr = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    break;

case CTLCOLOR_EDIT: case CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX:
    pDC->SetTextColor(g_crBlack);
    pDC->SetBkColor(g_crWhite);
    hbr = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);      
    break;
}
```

Notice in the CTLCOLOR_STATIC there is a check for the IDC_EDIT controls.
My issue is if it is an edit control it shouldn't even be in the case to check and it should never pass the check and therefore the background of the edit control should never become blue. Also, the color is not set to white in any case inside the static case. However, the current checks work and when the radio is set to 0 both boxes are blue and if not they go white. In my static case the bkcolor is never set to white so why would it toggle correctly rather than always be blue or if it sees it as an edit and sets it to white, why isn't the bkcolor always white?

Is an edit control supposed to be able to be checked in a static case?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that edit control that is read-only or disabled sends `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC ` instead of `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`. Maybe that's your case?

Comment: @Dialecticus That was my case I found `::SendMessage(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_SP_FROM)->GetSafeHwnd(), EM_SETREADONLY, ES_READONLY, 0);` in a different function. When I previously looked at the MSDN I didn't notice that it functioned as static when readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A static control, or an edit control that is read-only or disabled, sends the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn.